# CoordinatorLayout does not display with targetSdkVersion 28 in AndroidStudio 3.1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, coordinator-layout

I'm using the latest version of android studio (3.1.4), along with latest SDK version (28).

The layout does not get rendered in the design tab,  I'm using coordinator layout.

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FireBaseInterfaseActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_notas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Design TAB picture:**

Design TAB image

[image]

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Can you [edit] and post layout file code in which you're using `CoordinatorLayout`? And also screenshot of the preview window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your targetSdkVersion to 27 (File --> Project Structure --> app --> Flavors)

and check your build.gradle(Module:app) file for this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

if you already have this dependency and it still isn't working try adding this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

I hope this helps you :)